# Unable to deploy web application using web deployment tool

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles

I deployed an application on Azure. Now, I setup my MvcWebRole project to publish directly to my role instance through web deploy.  (refering link : http://www.wadewegner.com/2010/12/using-web-deploy-with-windows-azure-for-rapid-development/ )

However, whenever I am trying to publish an application, it is giving an error like:

```
Error 1 Web deployment task failed.(Remote agent (URL http://mywebsvr/MSDEPLOYAGENTSERVICE) could not be contacted. 
Make sure the remote agent service is installed and started on the target computer.)

The requested resource does not exist, or the requested URL is incorrect.

Error details:

Remote agent (URL http://mywebsvr/MSDEPLOYAGENTSERVICE) could not be contacted. Make sure the remote agent service is installed and started on the target computer.

An unsupported response was received. The response header 'MSDeploy.Response' was '' but 'v1' was expected.

The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found. 0 0 CPE Tracking System
```

I read some articles and most of them advise to make sure the remote agent service is already started by issuing the command "net start msdepsvc".  But I don't know why issuing this command will return the error "The service name is invalid".

How come the server can't understand the parameter msdepsvc? 
Would anybody please help!

Thanks,
TAdhav

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your reply. Problem is resolved now. The user trying to deploy an application didn't have permission on machine.

Reference link: http://forums.iis.net/p/1176267/1974277.aspx

Link Used for setting up permission on server is: http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/155/an-overview-of-feature-delegation-in-iis-70/

Thanks,

TA

Answer (score 2):

I would try to use the new SDK 1.4 Refresh.  That includes an officially supported WebDeploy tooling now and is much more likely to work without hiccups.

More information and link to download here:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazure/archive/2011/04/15/now-available-windows-azure-sdk-1-4-refresh-with-webdeploy-integration.aspx